# What is the state of affairs on Nootka Sound by the end of season 1?

Tags: plot-explanation, taboo

During the course of the 1st season of [*Taboo*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3647998/) James Delaney is constantly struggling to keep all the various forces, primarily the British and American governments and the East India Company, lusting for his heritage of Nootka Sound in a difficult balance against each other. This leads him to make various kinds of offers and deals with the respective parties throughout the series.

At the end of the season, it was thus maybe not too easy to recollect all those political issues and deals revolving around Nootka Sound and I'm not sure if I got lost at some point. What I wonder is what James and his posse can actually do with this piece of land now.

- I know that very early on he directs for Nootka Sound to go to the Americans upon his death, in order to keep the British from killing him. This obviously didn't happen but should still be in effect.
- He tries to get a monopoly for trading furs for tea with Canton (although, it's not clear if that's just a ruse). But I'm not sure if he actually got it. And I don't know if the absence of such a monopoly would keep him from making any trade at all, or just have a hard time against the competition.
- They also mention at some point that the only good he will be able to trade would be gunpowder, but it's not entirely clear to me why (because the peace negotiations between Britain and the USA failed?). But he also needed the gunpowder for bargaining with the Americans and I'm not sure if he is going to sell *all* of it to Colonnade.

Now, I'm not asking what would happen after the end of the series, I know that's speculation and I'm sure neither of the big players will leave matters be just because he left Britain (and there's apparently more seasons planned already). I'm also not sure James ever cared that much about any trade monopolies anyway.

Rather I'm asking what the **official state of affairs is in the Nootka Sound situation after the first season**. Does he have the right to settle there and under what jurisdiction is it? Is it completely out of both the United States and Great Britain? Would the matters around it actually calm down a little once he officially settles it (or maybe once the war is over and the borders fixed?) or is it bound to remain a constant cause for fighting? And what are his trading options? Did he make any kind of deal that I don't recollect or is he out on his own on the commercial front now? It would be helpful if I could get a little **rundown of, maybe not the entire plot, but the developments around Nootka Sound during the season** and what this all basically means for its current political and commercial situation.

<sub>(I'm also not too interested in the reality of Nootka Sound's history, as I think the show took quite a few liberties with it anyway. I'm looking for answers based on how the plot around Nootka and its relation to James developed in the show and maybe with a little reasoning based on the show's (supposedly accurate) historical *framework*.)</sub>